# Pydantic: JSON-encoding dictionary keys

Tags: python, json, pydantic

When using (hashable) objects as dictionary keys, calling `.json()` fails because while the values are encoded, the keys aren't:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import dict
from datetime import datetime

class Foo(BaseModel): 
  date: datetime 
  sdict: Dict[datetime, str]

  class Config:
    json_encoders = {
      datetime: repr
    }

foo = Foo(date=datetime.now(), sdict={datetime.now(): 'now'})
foo                                                                                                                                                                                                      
# Foo(date=datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 3, 12, 9, 55, 36105), sdict={datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 3, 12, 9, 55, 36114): 'now'})
foo.json()
TypeError: keys must be a string

# to prove the other way around works:
class Foo(BaseModel): 
  date: datetime 
  sdict: Dict[str, datetime]

  class Config:
    json_encoders = {
      datetime: repr
    }

foo = Foo(date=datetime.now(), sdict={'now': datetime.now()})
foo.json()                                                                                                                                                                                               
# '{"date": "datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 3, 12, 13, 30, 606880)", "sdict": {"now": "datetime.datetime(2021, 9, 3, 12, 13, 30, 606884)"}}'
```

This is because the `default=` param in `json.dumps()` which is ultimately used to dump doesn't encode dictionary keys. Defining a JSON encoder class does work, but it doesn't work for me for other reasons.

I've seen `TypedDict` in pydantic but it doesn't seem to fix the issue. Actually, I'm unsure what's the use of `TypedDict`, since AFAICS you need to define every key in the dict, which makes it analogue to a static object?

My use-case is that I need to represent the following idea:

```py
{
  "report": {
    "warehouses": {
      warehouse.id: {
        "name": warehouse.name,
        "address": warehouse.address,
      }
      for warehouse in warehouses
  }
}
```

and `warehouse.id` is an `Identifier` object which can convert to different formats on demand, and which the json encoder will convert to a string.

Anyone knows of a way other than a dictionary where I can add arbitrary keys to an object in a way that will be affected by the json encoder, or some other way of serializing?

Answer (score 0):

One of the options of solving the problem is using custom [`json_dumps`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#custom-json-deserialisation) function for pydantic model, inside which to make custom serialization, I did it by inheriting from [`JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder).

For example, like this:

```py
import json
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Dict
from datetime import datetime


class CustomEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def _transform(self, v):
        res = v
        if isinstance(v, datetime):
            res = v.isoformat()
        # else other variants
        return self._encode(res)

    def _encode(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, dict):
            return {self._transform(k): self._transform(v) for k, v in obj.items()}
        else:
            return obj

    def encode(self, obj):
        return super(CustomEncoder, self).encode(self._encode(obj))


def custom_dumps(values, *, default):
    return CustomEncoder().encode(values)


class Foo(BaseModel):
    date: datetime
    sdict: Dict[datetime, str]

    class Config:
        json_dumps = custom_dumps


foo = Foo(date=datetime.now(), sdict={datetime.now(): 'now'})
Foo(date=datetime(2021, 9, 3, 12, 9, 55, 36105), sdict={datetime(2021, 9, 3, 12, 9, 55, 36114): 'now'})
print(foo.json())
```

```
{"date": "2021-09-07T16:02:51.070159", "sdict": {"2021-09-07T16:02:51.070164": "now"}}
```